# GridBagLayout component size is dependent on JFrame size

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, size, gridbaglayout

I have the following program (simplified version of my actual program):

**MyPanel.java:**

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    
    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;

    public MyPanel(int width, int height){
        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(width, height);

        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        layeredPane.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

        setPreferredSize(dimension);
        setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    }
}
```

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main{

    private static int WIDTH = 500;
    private static int HEIGHT = 300;

    private static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        initFrame();
        addPanels();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void initFrame(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    }

    private static void addPanels(){
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;
        MyPanel panel1 = new MyPanel(200, 300);
        frame.add(panel1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        MyPanel panel2 = new MyPanel(300, 200);
        frame.add(panel2, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        MyPanel panel3 = new MyPanel(300, 100);
        frame.add(panel3, gbc);
    }
}
```

---

**Expectation:**

I want to create a 500x300 sized JFrame that has GridBagLayout. I want to divide this layout into 2 columns, further dividing the right column horizontally into 2 parts. My goal is to set the cell sizes precisely with the help of setting the preferredSize-s of the MyPanel components added into the layout.

This whole idea is based on the Oracle documentation of the GridBagLayout:

> *Essentially, GridBagLayout places components in rectangles (cells) in a grid, and then uses the components' preferred sizes to determine how big the cells should be.*
>
> > source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

---

**Problem:**

GridBagLayout seems to add "outer margins" to itself and I can't fit the manually sized components into the JFrame without somehow...shrinking it. Running the code above results in something like this:
[image]

The image shows the 500x300 JFrame rendered in the given size, but the components don't match the manually set sizes.

However, if I increase the `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` values to the following:

```
private static int WIDTH = 1000;
private static int HEIGHT = 600;
```

I get this result:
[image]

This time all the MyPanel components were rendered in their given sizes, but the JFrame is far too big. I want the components to fill up the entire JFrame with the given size.

---

**Question:**

What could cause this? How can I set manually the sizes of the components without running into this issue?

**Notes:**

I am aware of the `GridBagConstraints.weightx/y` variables, but my goal is to prevent the layout manager from setting the sizes of the components so those options don't seem ideal.

Every help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your concept of a Swing GUI is backward.  You determine the size of the individual Swing components and use a Swing layout manager to size the resulting `JPanels` and `JFrame`.  You shouldn't care (within reason) what the final size of the `JFrame` is.  The `JFrame` has decorations like a title bar and side margins that you're not taking into account.

Comment: You were right, I completely misunderstood what Layout managers are for. I managed to  fix the problem by removing the setPreferredSize and setBounds method calls on the JFrame and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comment of [@Gilbert Le Blanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300257/gilbert-le-blanc), I was able to fix my code.

Removing the

```
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
frame.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

lines from **Main.java** and calling `frame.pack();` at the end of the `main` method solved the problem.

The problem was caused by my misunderstanding of layout managers. You don't need to set the exact size of the `JFrame`, but only my components in the GridBagLayout. The GridBagLayout manager will handle the rest and set my frame size according to the components in it.